# Make member vectors out of tuples in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of tuples/lists.
Example:

```
a = [[1,2], [2,4], [3,6]]
```

Given all sub-lists are the same length I want to split them and receive lists/vectors for each member.

Or in one `[[1,2,3],[2,4,6]]`
Every solution using numpy or default lists would be appretiated.

I have not found a way to do this pythonicly, or efficiently by using any other feature than loops:

```
def vectorise_pairs(pairs):
    return [[p[0] for p in pairs],
            [p[1] for p in pairs]
           ]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `np.array(a).T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged numpy, `my_array.T` transposes `my_array`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1,2], [2,4], [3,6]]
>>> np.array(a).T
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

Alternatively, you can use `np.transpose` (which even accepts lists).

```
>>> np.transpose(a)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

Comment: This answer is correct and seems the easiest. Didn't think of transposition. However it leads to another problem. I will update my question.

Comment: @Meph changing your question once it has been answered is not well received here. Please ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: so then a new question

Comment: @Meph thanks, I'll look into it once you have posted it.

Comment: [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177424/make-member-vectors-out-of-tuples-in-python-while-preserving-further-sub-listing)

Answer (score 4):

```
first, second = zip(*a)
print(first, second)
```

outputs

```
(1, 2, 3) (2, 4, 6)
```

If you need lists or numpy arrays you can convert them:

```
first, second = list(first), list(second)
first, second = np.array(first), np.array(second)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex's solution works well as a general transposition of any Python iterable. If you have some reason to specifically want to use Numpy, you could also use the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2], [2,4], [3,6]])
first, second = a.T
# OR,
first = a[:, 0]
second = a[:, 1]  # etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the official documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
a = [[1,2], [2,4], [3,6]]

[[row[i] for row in a] for i in range(len(a[0]))]
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]]
```