# Make member vectors out of tuples in python while preserving further sub-listings

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array.

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [2,4], [3,6]])
and `np.array([[1,2,3],[2,4,6]])` is wanted.
```

And in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175298/make-member-vectors-out-of-tuples-in-python) it was established that to get the pairs to align in 2 separate new vectors, one for each pair-member, we should use `a.T` transposition of the matrix.

However this does not apply if numpy arrays are further embedded.

```
>>>b
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],
       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],
       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],
       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

I want:

```
>>>b.operation
    array([[[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2]]
           [[3, 4],[3, 4],[3, 4],[3, 4]]])
```

But I get

```
>>>b.T
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]],
       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

Which of course makes sense, since transposition seems to flip the shape around. `(4, 2, 2) -> (2, 2, 4)` But

I also tried reassigning the shape, but I guess looking at how it lies in memory:

```
b in mem : 1234123412341234
b.T in mem : 1111333322224444
```

there is no way this will work.

```
i'd need : 1212121234343434
```

Any advice in how to handle this properly or in an efficient way?

Comment: transpose takes an argument. play with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [np.moveaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html#numpy.moveaxis). I found it by looking at the [numpy array manipulation routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html).

For your use case, this demonstrates the desired usage:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([[1,2], [2,4], [3,6]])

In [2]: b = np.array([
   ...:     [[1, 2],
   ...:      [3, 4]],
   ...:     [[1, 2],
   ...:      [3, 4]],
   ...:     [[1, 2],
   ...:      [3, 4]],
   ...:     [[1, 2],
   ...:      [3, 4]]])
   ...:

In [3]: np.moveaxis(a, 0, 1)
Out[3]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6]])

In [4]: np.moveaxis(b, 0, 1)
Out[4]:
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[3, 4],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]]])
```

Before editing this answer I recommended [np.rollaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis) (in which case you would use `np.rollaxis(a, 1))`, but then I noticed in that linked documentation that np.moveaxis is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired outcome by specifying the axes for transpose. Which is faster if you don't mind the slightly more cumbersome syntax.

```
import numpy as np
b= np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
             [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
             [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
             [[1, 2], [3, 4]]])

%timeit b.transpose((1,0,2))
# 393 ns ± 11.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit np.rollaxis(b, 1)
# 1.8 µs ± 52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Output is  (shape 2,4,2)

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[3, 4],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]]])
```

as desired.